# TempData lost when using asp.net core 2.1 identity on localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.1, tempdata

Installed new `asp.net core 2.1 identity` (the one using RCL) to play with it.
Scaffolded Login, Registration and Profile pages. Checking profile page:

```
Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.Manage.Index.cshtml.cs
```

I came accross this property:

```
    [TempData]
    public string StatusMessage { get; set; }
```

which is set when updating profile page:

```
    StatusMessage = "Your profile has been updated";
    return RedirectToPage();
```

The funny thing is the message is not shown when running locally. The funnier one is when I publish it to Azure, it works.

My `Startup.cs` do have config as indicated by ofiical docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.1#tempdata

which goes:

```
 .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider()
```

and

```
 app.UseSession();
```

Here is the full source code:

https://github.com/kedzior-io/dotnetpwa/tree/model-status-message-is-empty-on-redirect

Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the official docs you're referencing? Just so I'm on the same page with this.

Comment: question updated

Comment: Not sure why yours isn't working, but here's an example of the things you said, and it's working for me locally. https://github.com/afmorris/StackOverflow-52674151. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Yep, seems to be working ok. Anyways, here is my source code: https://github.com/kedzior-io/dotnetpwa/tree/model-status-message-is-empty-on-redirect . Looking for differences.

Answer (score 3):

So looks like offical docs are no good:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.1#tempdata

Docs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddMvc()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
        .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();

    services.AddSession();
}
```

Should be:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddSession(); // That should be BEFORE .AddMvc()

    services.AddMvc()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
        .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();


}
```

Thanks @Tony Morris

Answer (score 2):

I'm using aspnet core 2.2, and in my case changing the order as suggested by Artur's answer didn't work.

I solved this by following the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/gdpr?view=aspnetcore-2.2#tempdata-provider-and-session-state-cookies-are-not-essential), where it says:

> Session state cookies are not essential. Session state isn't functional when tracking is disabled. The following code makes session cookies essential:

```
services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
```

Having this set solves the issue no matter if it's placed before or after `services.AddMvc()`

Answer (score 0):

My site's cookie policy meant the TempData cookie was not being saved. So I added code to mark the cookie as "essential":

```
services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddCookieTempDataProvider(t => t.Cookie.IsEssential = true);
```